# Java - no-duplicate collection without iterator allocation

Tags: java, memory-management, game-engine

**Problem**

I'm developing a game where I need to minimise memory allocation and GC activity. For this I need a collection with non-duplicate values minimising memory allocation during access operations. I am prepared to compromise with a slight decrease of performance to make up for the improved "garbage generation".

**Solutions Considered (including discarded ones for reference)**

1. **Extend ArrayList** to include a check on *add(E e)* for duplicates and do nothing if value exists. (this may include other methods too)
2. **Use HashSet (discarded)** - iteration of elements causes instantiation of a new Iterator which defeats the requirement of minimal memory allocation during access.
3. **Convert HashSet to ArrayList (discarded)** - creates more memory allocaiton than HashSet iteration.

**Question**

*Is the extention of ArrayList to prevent duplicate values a sensible way to achieve non-duplicate collection with minimal memory allocation? Are there alternative methods I should consider?*

**Notes**

Most advised solutions to eliminate duplicates in ArrayList I have seen refer to using HashSet or other object instantiation which defeat my minimal memory allocation requirement. The only implementation I can think of is a basic "for iteration" of the ArrayList checking equality of the added value against each existing element.

```
Class NonDuplicateList extends ArrayList{
    @Override
    boolean add(E e){
        for(int i = 0; i < this.size(); i++){
            if(this.get(i).equals(e)
                return false;
        }
        return super.add(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: An `Iterator` object is rather cheap in terms of memory. I wonder if you don't go too fast in your conclusions and so on your requirements.

Comment: @davidxxx it is "rather cheap" but in the context of a game environment (huge volume of access operations and low-latency requirement) it adds up. I appreciate the scepticism expected for this kind of niche problem but the overall objective is to obtain near-zero allocation in the game frame life-cycle, generally you would achieve this by pooling / reusing objects which is rather problematic when it comes to iterators.

Comment: side note if memory usage is a big concern you might want to consider using a LinkedList, that way you won't have any resizing operations either.

Comment: @Todoy thanks - less concerned about memory footprint, decision on LinkedList vs ArrayList will probably be driven by access performance (read / insert) on a case by case basis rather than memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have here isn't a `List`: [`List.add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-E-), by contract, has to return `true`:

> Returns:
>
> `true` (as specified by `Collection.add(E)`)

You could throw an `IllegalArgumentException` instead:

> Throws:
>
> `IllegalArgumentException` - if some property of this element prevents it from being added to this list

but having to handle an exception is gross.

Additionally, extending `ArrayList` is *rarely* the right thing to do: in this case, `ArrayList`s allow you to add any element to the end (provided there is enough memory), so your class would not be Liskov-substitutable.

Plus, of course, you've got to override all the other methods that let you add elements to the list: `add` (the other overloads), `addAll`, `set`, all the methods on `subList` and `listIterator` etc etc. This is hard to do correctly.

---

Instead, use *composition*:

```
class NonDuplicateList<E> {
    private final List<E> delegate = new ArrayList<>();

    boolean add(E e){
        // contains is easier! ArrayList.contains does not use an iterator.
        if (delegate.contains(e)) return false;
        return delegate.add(e);
    }

    // Other methods you may require
}
```

By defining your own class like this, you aren't required to conform to any contracts that you have not designed yourself; and you can expose a much smaller set of methods, making it far less work to maintain the no-duplicates property of your list.

Comment: Thanks, certainly cleaner implementation of the concept.

Comment: For the record I implemented the no-duplicate ArrayList solution (via composition)  replacing iterator-based access and the GC pauses graph is now a nice flat line :-)